# sometimes, wkhtmltopdf windows process not exiting

Tags: php, drupal, wkhtmltopdf

We are using wkhtmltopdf with Drupal on windows environment. The generated PDF's are really great when it worked. But, rarely we are running into a weird issue.

When we tried to generate the PDF, the page loads forever. I found the corresponding wkhtmltopdf.exe process is still running in the task manager and never exits. Interestingly, the PDF generates successfully if I kill the windows process manually.

Wondering if anybody ran into similar issues with wkhtmltopdf?

our environment is: Drupal 6 + PHP 5 + Apache + Windows

Comment: It is probably asking the user a question which your script is not answering, and my guess is that it is asking "the destination file already exists, do you want to overwrite it?". You should do a `file_exists()` on the destination file before calling wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for your quick reply. We are using time stamp as part of the file name.

Comment: OK no worries - I still think the most likely answer is that wkhtmltopdf is hanging waiting for user input, you should use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to collect all output from `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and log it as it happens - with this method of execution you don't have to wait for the program to finish before you can access the data.

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for pointing me to "proc_open". The current code is already using it. I added more debugging statements to troubleshoot further. I found out that "proc_open" call is the one that is blocking. I mean the control never returned after this call until I killed the windows process manually. From your statement above, we can make that call as non blocking. Will look into it in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: Update: Seems, "proc_open" is not the root cause for blocking. "stream_get_contents" for PDF is the one blocking. This call is made right after "proc_open".

Comment: Update: I am hoping the issue is fixed finally in our case :) Somebody commented it on one of the PHP manual pages. Lost the link though :( Fix is: when you pass the descriptor to "proc_open", pass append mode for error stream instead of write mode. Not sure how it fixed it, but it is working in my case. Hoping, it might help somebody too.

Comment: Thanks Vick, not sure yet whether the append trick solves this 'hanging' problem (its a problem which rarely happens), but it doesn't harm the process either.

Comment: You can answer your own question when you found the answer :) The stderr/stdin confusion often with wkhtmltopdf is that it outputs two things; the pdf and the user feedback. One stream outputs the pdf and one stream outputs the messages you see if you execute in the console.